# DateTime object in Memgraph

Tags: graph-databases, memgraphdb

I am working with Memgraph and I am using dates. I need to have the date in a specific format like "MM:DD:YYYY" and others but what if I just have the DateTime object passed?

Comment: Your question is rather vague. In order to get a tested  answer it will be helpful if you can show the things you have already tried. Also please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have a datetime object saved as **Date** in Memgraph, then it needs to be in the appropriate format. For strings, the date format is specified by ISO 8601: `YYYY-MM-DD` or `YYYYMMDD` or `YYYY-MM`.